# How to access variables in kotlin without invoking its setter and getter

Tags: kotlin

I am working on a library where any change in argument refreshes the view. In `refresh()` function, I am setting some arguments' values to default values.

```
var viewAlpha= 255
        set(value) {
            field = value
            refresh()
        }

fun refresh() {
    viewAlpha = 255
    invalidate()
}
```

This is causing StackOverflowError due to obvious reasons.

> Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Is it possible to access variables in kotlin without invoking its setter when we are accessing it in the same class. Similar to what we do in java.

Comment: Why do you need that? In this way your setter is useless because there is no way to set `viewAlpha` value not 255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to provide you good ol' backing field to get out of setter-refres cycle:

```
private var _viewAlpha = 255

var viewAlpha
        get() {
            return _viewAlpha
        }
        set(value) {
            _viewAlpha = value
            refresh()
        }

fun refresh() {
    _viewAlpha = 255
    invalidate()
}
```

If you want to simplify your logic for multiple fields you can abstract this implementation into separate class and use callback call with direct setter that will work without `refresh` invocation. Like this:

```
class Field(val onSetCb: (Field) -> Unit) {

    private var viewAlpha = 255

    fun get() {
        return viewAlpha
    }

    fun set(value: Int) {
        setDirect(value)
        onSetCb(this)
    }

    fun setDirect(value: Int) {
        viewAlpha = value;
    }
}

// Elsewhere...

fun refresh(field: Field) {
    field.setDirect(255)
    invalidate()
}

val f = Field(::refresh)
f.set(255)
```

Comment: Better to make `_viewAlpha` private.

Comment: @Ircover agree, added access restriction.

Comment: Actually, I have 15+ variables and this solution can generate a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @Shubh You probably need to abstract this logic into some separate class and replace viewAlpha and other 15+ variables with it. I sense a fellow Android developer here, as had same problems in context of Android.

Comment: @Shubh updated answer to contain example of that class.